# Timestamp in sequelize 1.7.3

Tags: node.js, express, timestamp, sails.js, sequelize.js

hi i want to save date and time according to eastern time, my sequelize model is:

```
var  objName= sequelize.define('tbl_name',{
        orders_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
        customers_id:Sequelize.INTEGER,         
        date_purchased: { type: Sequelize.DATE, defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW },
        order_total:Sequelize.INTEGER,


    },
    {
        tableName: 'tbl_name',
        timestamps: false
    });
```

now i want to use timestamps somehow in it and want to save (Eastern Standard Time), can someone guide me how can i do this.

**Note:** i am using mysql and sailsjs .
Thanks.

**EDIT**

also used following two snippets  but then it saves `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

```
date_purchased: { type: Sequelize.DATE, defaultValue: sequelize.literal("FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + (3600 * 2))") },

date_purchased: { type: Sequelize.DATE, defaultValue: sequelize.literal("(now() at time zone 'EST')") }
```

Comment: Do you want to save the date in eastern time to display the date in eastern time. I don't want to second guess your question, but most dates are saved in UTC and then displayed in the timezone in question.

Comment: How are you using sails.js with sequelize? sails.js uses the Waterline ORM

Comment: @Meeker yes i want to save date and time into EST

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to want to manipulate your dates (add, subtract, compare)? If NOT then just save them as pre-formatted strings.

Otherwise you are going to run into problems with this approach of saving "Eastern time" that are beyond sails. Remember eastertime is the same as UTC, just with an offset and this offset changes depending on if your in Daylight savings or no.

MySQL by default will use the system time zone internally but it is possible to define a different time zone for the MySQL server globally or even per transaction. However, MYSQL is still going to save the time in a UTC, all your telling MYSQL is to transform during read/writes as if we were in eastern timezone.

This can be tricky when dealing with many variables such as your application server, your db adapter and finally your DB.

The safest thing to do is to save all dates as UTC (have your server setup in a UTC system time) and then display them in the correct timezone via the application layer.

You have to ask yourself. "Where are my dates coming from". Are they all being generated within the database itself (like your code above)? Are they being generated by the application server (such as sails creating the date and then inserting it) or will dates come form the client (browsers have their own timezone issues).

If you do want to manipulate/compare them, then your best making sure your dates save UTC and then manipulating the timezone when its displayed to the user. Consider Daylight Savings Time (it changes this weekend!).

How to accomplish this will vary depending on your setup and answering many of the questions I have issued above.

I know that I stopped using Date/Time methods a while ago and instead use integer to store all my dates with a UnixTimestamp. Then I format that into the correct timezone before showing to the client. This ensures that my dates will not be unduly transformed no matter what DB i'm using or where the server is. This is just a personal preference, but I find it has elevated a big headache.